# Non-classist phrase to replace "Low-rent" or "White trash"?

Tags: phrase-requests

As a clear example of the negative connotations of these phrases, I'm thinking of the constellation of traits reflected in the lower-class family portrayed in "Million Dollar Baby" (which, in my experience, can exist in dysfunctional higher economic class families): selfish, belligerent, lacking in basic humanity.
The closest phrases I can think of are "uncivilized" and "primitive", but these don't really capture the dysfunction. Something better?

Comment: I'm not sure that if someone referred to me as "uncivilized" or "primitive" that I would consider either term as neutral rather than negative. I'm not entirely clear what sort of term you're looking for. Wouldn't it be better to avoid the stereotype altogether?

Comment: {**disadvantaged** [adjective]
(of a person or area) in unfavourable circumstances, especially with regard to financial or social opportunities.
"disadvantaged groups such as the unemployed"} [[Oxford Languages courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=disadvantaged+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=disadvantaged+me&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqDQgAEAAYgwEYsQMYgAQyDQgAEAAYgwEYsQMYgAQyBggBEEUYOTIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIICAkQABgWGB6oAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)] mirrors the passive use of a verb, distancing ...

Comment: agency of those referred to. But the whole notion of 'uncivilised' / 'dysfunctional' _must_ carry a [semantically] negative tone.

Comment: I agree with the above about offensiveness, but race, place of origin, and urban/rural may affect what terms are used. Not everybody will have seen *Million Dollar Baby*, so you may want to be a bit more precise. Also sociological approach (the Marxist term *Lumpenproletariat* for instance doesn't have much currency outside Marxist analysis). You could read [Underclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underclass) but it's a controversial term too.

Comment: You should elaborate on what you mean by "lacking in basic humanity".  Having no empathy? Unable to see, unwilling to try to see, the world from another person's perspective?

Comment: As rich and poor families can be dysfunctional, you have your word there.

Comment: I really have no idea what exact set of traits you're trying to describe. The term "white trash" generally (in my mind, at least) involves describing people as behaving in ways seen as stereotypically uneducated and lower-class, not as being "selfish" or "belligerent."

Comment: That movie does not have those kinds of characters except for poor white young woman. Also, why do you need low rent? That term is fine. Two boxers and a poor young lady do not white trash make. And the rich are usually nastier than the poor. What in the heck are  you trying to say?

Comment: low, middle and upper class are not always classist.

Comment: As I said, I was thinking of the family of the young women:  mother, brother, and sister. To spell it out, overweight mother just bullies daughter into signing over money to her and ignores her suffering, brother squares off with Clint Eastwood character with a sarcastic grin, sister just smirks at everything and says a snide thing or two about everyone else.

Comment: That behavior is not exclusive to a lower class. Think of the TV series: *Succession* I prefer neurotic to the American-coined and misused dysfunctional.

Answer (score 0):

**Disreputable**

> not trusted or respected; thought to have a bad character [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disreputable)

**Uncouth**

> behaving in a rude, unpleasant way [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uncouth)

Obi-Wan says of Mos Eisley:

> You will never find a more wretched hive of **scum** and **villainy**.

So maybe you could use one of those.

If you wanted to emphasise self interest, perhaps [**cutthroat**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cutthroat).

Answer (score 0):

A single non-classist word for "selfish, belligerent, lacking in basic humanity" ...

The word **[sociopathic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sociopathic)** comes to mind.

The final phrase, "lacking in basic humanity", is what pushes things over into the realm of pathology, IMO.  But if you mean by that something closer to "having no sense of decency or fairness", then **sociopathic** would be too extreme.

If the trio of traits is "selfish, belligerent, and petty" then **stunted** could work. A figurative use where "basic humanity" is seen as the result of emotional *growth*.

Comment: Excellent point (I felt subconsciously "basic humanity" went too far).  Perhaps "petty and dysfunctional" is the best I can hope for.  It is interesting that there exists bigoted stereotypes for "Million Dollar Baby" families, but not for "Succession" families.

Comment: The situation that arises when such a person lives or works with others like themselves is *dysfunctional*.

Comment: There is nothing sociopathic about the characters in that movie.

Comment: @Lambie: I say nothing about that movie in my answer, as I've never seen it. I quote OP's description of the traits (twice) and specifically discuss them. My answer has nothing directly to do with the movie and doesn't need to address the movie, as it is only an example OP uses.

Comment: Well, I took it as an exemplification of his idea, which also has nothing to do with sociopathic, a psychology classification.

Comment: OP and I have discussed what was meant by "lacking in basic humanity".  It's as if you looked only at the bolded words and didn't bother to read the answer. I only point this out because you're a repeat offender in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

There are many adjectives available to describe people who act badly, some of which hint at underlying causes or group traits, and others that just portray unwelcome behavior:

Uneducated, ignorant, immoral, dishonest, violent, disruptive, ill-mannered, bad-tempered, undisciplined, dishonorable, unforgiving, uncouth, barbaric, cruel, childish, juvenile, rude, and on and on.